# What are the conditions needed by $n$ so that $2^{n+1}5^n-1$ is a prime number?

Tags: number-theory

What are the conditions needed by $n$ so that $2^{n+1}5^n-1$ is a prime number?

I am investigating prime numbers $2^{n+1}5^n-1$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and I found out that there are prime numbers that satisfy the said condition like $19, 199, 1999, 199999, ..., 199999999999999999999999999,...$.

Comment: you forgot 1999. I think.

Comment: Wait... you didn't. And there is no 19999. Sry. (How do you delete comments?)

Comment: @jonnytan999 it is included in my example

Answer (score 2):

The exponents $n$ are listed at [A002957](https://oeis.org/A002957) in the OEIS.

The only conditions I can think of are the usual modular conditions. For example, $n$ can't be $4\pmod6$ or the number will be divisible by 7, it can't be $6\pmod{16}$ or the number will be divisible by 17, it can't be $1\pmod{18}$ or the number will be divisible by 19, etc.

Comment: kindly elaborate those conditions. I cant easily connect the modular conditions. could you please explain it further. Maybe we could make a more general form for n. Thanks

Comment: @MKA: Do you not know what they mean, or just don't know how to find others?

Comment: both of them sir

Comment: @MKA: That's more than I can teach in a comment. See https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic or similar resources.